# how can i put widget next row using tkinter pack() method?

Tags: python, tkinter

> how can i put widget next row using tkinter  pack() method??  i used
>   pack(side= LEFT) but i can't make like my upload picture . pack(side=
>   LEFT) is only left...           i can't put next row widget. i
>   wonder..

[[image: I can't like this image using tkinter.. click to show image]]

```
from tkinter import *   
app = Tk()

app.title('')
app.geometry("800x1200")



Label(app, text = 'a:').pack(side= LEFT)
a = Entry(app)
a.insert(0, "")
a.pack(side= LEFT)


Label(app, text = 'b:').pack(side= LEFT)
b = Entry(app)
b.insert(0, "")
b.pack(side= LEFT)




Label(app, text = 'c:').pack(side= LEFT)
c = Entry(app)
c.insert(0, "")
c.pack(side= LEFT)



Label(app, text = 'd:').pack(side= LEFT)
d = Entry(app)
d.insert(0, "")
d.pack(side= LEFT)

Label(app, text = 'e:').pack(side= LEFT)
e = Entry(app)
e.insert(0, "")
e.pack(side= LEFT)





Label(app, text = 'f:').pack(side= LEFT)
f = Entry(app)
f.insert(0, "")
f.pack(side= LEFT)


Label(app, text = 'g:').pack(side= LEFT)
g = Entry(app)
g.insert(0, "")
g.pack(side= LEFT)


Label(app, text = 'h:').pack(side= LEFT)
h = Entry(app)
h.insert(0, "")
h.pack(side= LEFT)



Label(app, text = '').pack()
text = Text(app, width=100,height=12)
text.insert('1.0', "text")
text.pack()




Label(app, text = '').pack()
text2 = Text(app, width=100,height=12)
text2.insert('1.0', "text")
text2.pack()



Button(app, text = 'save ').pack()

app.mainloop()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/34545.py", line 2, in
>   
>      Label(app, text = 'a:').pack(side= LEFT) NameError: name 'Label' is not defined

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Use additional Frames to group your widgets. Any tkinter tutorial covers this kind of layout question. Read one of them. Also, this may well be a duplicate question with an answer already on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `pack`, then you need to put buttons A, B, C, and D in one frame, and buttons E, F, G, and H in another frame. Another option would be to put all of those buttons in a single frame using `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

This is code:

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk  
app = Tk()

app.title('')
app.geometry("800x1200")



tk.Label(app, text = 'a:').pack(side= LEFT)
a = Entry(app)
a.insert(0, "")
a.pack(side= LEFT)


tk.Label(app, text = 'b:').pack(side= LEFT)
b = Entry(app)
b.insert(0, "")
b.pack(side= LEFT)




tk.Label(app, text = 'c:').pack(side= LEFT)
c = Entry(app)
c.insert(0, "")
c.pack(side= LEFT)



tk.Label(app, text = 'd:').pack(side= LEFT)
d = Entry(app)
d.insert(0, "")
d.pack(side= LEFT)

tk.Label(app, text = 'e:').pack(side= LEFT)
e = Entry(app)
e.insert(0, "")
e.pack(side= LEFT)





tk.Label(app, text = 'f:').pack(side= LEFT)
f = Entry(app)
f.insert(0, "")
f.pack(side= LEFT)


tk.Label(app, text = 'g:').pack(side= LEFT)
g = Entry(app)
g.insert(0, "")
g.pack(side= LEFT)


tk.Label(app, text = 'h:').pack(side= LEFT)
h = Entry(app)
h.insert(0, "")
h.pack(side= LEFT)



tk.Label(app, text = '').pack()
text = Text(app, width=100,height=12)
text.insert('1.0', "text")
text.pack()




tk.Label(app, text = '').pack()
text2 = Text(app, width=100,height=12)
text2.insert('1.0', "text")
text2.pack()



Button(app, text = 'save ').pack()

app.mainloop()
```

If you want to change place this button,entry or label I think you should use place(x=?,y=?)